# 2005 Volkswagen Jetta 2.5 L timing chain replacement

Tags: vw, jetta, timing-chain

Where does the timing chain get it get its rotation from? I have replaced everything I could possibly think of but the camshaft isn’t turning so it has to be the timing chain does the engine have to come out in order to replace it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said, "I have replaced everything I could possibly think of ..." ... could you please edit your question and elaborate on what exactly you have changed? What was the original reason why you were changing parts in the first place? What broke to cause this action?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, the timing chain and cam shaft get their rotation from the crankshaft. And it is not necessary to remove the engine to replace a timing chain.

Note that if the cam shaft is ***really*** not rotating, your engine is probably toast because you already have bent valves and possibly other damage. (The 2005 VW 2.5L is an [interference engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_engine).)

However, if you concluded that the cam shaft is not rotating because of a particular engine code that you're getting, there are other possibilities. The cam shaft position sensor could be bad, the plug that connects to it can be bad, the wire from the plug to the computer could be bad, the plug to the computer could be bad, or the computer itself could be bad.

This answer doesn't really get you closer to solving your problem. I suggest that you start a new question and give more specific details. What are the symptoms? What made you start changing parts? Do you have any engine codes? The more information you give, the more likely that someone here can help.